# CGRectIntersection requires scalar type?

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors

I am trying to check collisions of objects from a `NSMutableArray` against another object (using a `CGRect`) but it keeps saying the method requires a scalar type?!

Here is the method throwing the error:

```
-(void) checkSquareToCircleCollisions{
    NSMutableArray *array = [squares getSquares];

    for(int i = 0; i < [squares getCount]; i++){
        Square *s = [array objectAtIndex: i];
        CGRect rect1 = [player getRect];
        CGRect rect2 = [s getRect];

        //if(CGRectIntersection(rect1, rect2)){
            //[player setAlive: NO];
       // }

    } 
}
```

Comment: As a side note (beyond Stream's fix), don't preface getters with "get." It breaks KVC which is required by many parts of the system. A leading "get" means that you will be returning the value by reference.

Comment: I edited code and removed my answer. Current answer represents the better solution.

Comment: @Stream: [Please don't ever edit code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88627/how-far-can-i-refactor-someone-elses-code) except perhaps to fix typos in answers. You should never change the meaning of someone else's code on this site. If you believe answer code could be better, post your own answer. Changing the code in a question changes the question itself.

Comment: @W'rkncacnter Thank you for the note, and sorry for over-refactoring. I will remember this.

Comment: What's with all the `get` method prefixes. It's totally unconventional. Why bother creating a `getCount` method when there is a perfectly good `count` method for arrays? Apple even have a [style guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) that is worth reading.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`CGRectIntersectsRect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/etc/redirect/xcode/ios/30c85e/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntersectsRect), not `CGRectIntersection`.

`CGRectIntersectsRect` returns a boolean: YES if the rectangles intersect.  `CGRectIntersection` returns the `CGRect` that is the overlap (if any) between the two rectangles.

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(playerRect, squareRect)) {
    player.alive = NO;
}
```